# Getting an Intermittent Error through Windows Terminal Server: "Because of an error in data encryption this session will end"

Tags: windows, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

I have a user who is getting this error Intermittently from a terminal server session through windows 2003: "Because of an error in data encryption, this session will end". Any idea why this is happening and how to prevent it from happening in the future?

Comment: http://www.petri.co.il/network-issues-with-windows-server-2008-rdp-on-dell-servers.htm

Answer (score 0):

j.rightly has the correct answer, but it bears clarification (since the first half of that article's troubleshooting is off-base):

This is probably caused by your NIC's drivers; there is a faulty Large Send Offload in the drivers for certain Broadcom NICs.  Disable that option on the NIC's driver and the issues should stop.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be solved by simply uninstalling the Link-Layer Topology (Mapper I/O Driver and Responder) protocols, as well as the QoS Packet Scheduler service (you can add them back again afterwards) in the Local Area Connection of the client machine (not the server/target).  You must uninstall, not simply remove the checkmark next to the protocol or service.